MockMvc Response Body empty after forwarding successful login
I am testing a custom Login controller end point that works with a Custom Filter that accepts JSON post request and also provides remember me option.
I am learning this because the standard Username Password doesn't work very well with a JSON Api. So if I have a JavaScript front-end like React being served from the same port,
then the standard mechanism doesn't work well.
Everything works fine, except for one weird thing,
I understand that redirects require the client to make an extra request so I understand that i would need to use andDo(...) thanks to the answer to this question I asked a short while ago:
How to test POST request form submission with redirect in @SpringBootTest
But since forwarding happens on the server, I would expect the response to return as normal.
Here is the code: I have only added the code for the configuration file & test class for now, because everything is working fine,
I have added a screenshot from Postman that shows it works perfectly:
Here is the success handler that handles the forwarded request:
public class JsonAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/loggedin").forward(request, response);
    }
}


@WebMvcTest
@Import({SecurityConfig.class})
public class LogInTest {

    @MockBean
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @MockBean
    private MusersDao dao;

    @MockBean
    private MuserDetailsService muserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    void testUsernameNotFound() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(dao.findByUsername(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(null);
        Mockito.doThrow(UsernameNotFoundException.class).when(muserDetailsService).loadUserByUsername(Mockito.anyString());

        String loginBody = mapper.writeValueAsString(new LoginRequest("xxxx", "xxxx", false));

        mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/login")
                .content(loginBody)
                .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf())
        ).andExpect(result -> assertEquals(401, result.getResponse().getStatus()));
    }

    @Test
    void testInvalidPassword() throws Exception {
        Muser muser = new Muser(1, "Mama", "mama", "mama", LocalDateTime.now());
        List<MuserRole> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        Mockito.when(dao.findByUsername(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(muser);

        Mockito.when(muserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(Mockito.eq("mama"))).thenReturn(
            new MuserDetails(muser, roles)
        );

        String loginBody = mapper.writeValueAsString(new LoginRequest(
            "mama", "wrong-password", false)
        );

        mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/login")
                .content(loginBody)
                .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf())
        ).andExpect(result -> assertEquals(401, result.getResponse().getStatus()));

    }

    @Test
    void testValidPassword() throws Exception {
        Muser muser = new Muser(1, "Mama", "mama", "mama", LocalDateTime.now());
        List<MuserRole> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        Mockito.when(dao.findByUsername(Mockito.eq("mama"))).thenReturn(muser);

        Mockito.when(muserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(Mockito.eq("mama"))).thenReturn(
            new MuserDetails(muser, roles)
        );

        String loginRequest = mapper.writeValueAsString(new LoginRequest(
            "mama", "mama", false)
        );

         mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/login")
                .content(loginRequest)
                .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf())
        ).andExpect(result -> assertEquals(200, result.getResponse().getStatus()));
    }

    @Test
    void testValidLoginForwardUrl() throws Exception {
        Muser muser = new Muser(1, "Mama", "mama", "mama", LocalDateTime.now());
        List<MuserRole> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        Mockito.when(dao.findByUsername(Mockito.eq("mama"))).thenReturn(muser);

        Mockito.when(muserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(Mockito.eq("mama"))).thenReturn(
            new MuserDetails(muser, roles)
        );

        String loginRequest = mapper.writeValueAsString(new LoginRequest(
            "mama", "mama", false)
        );

        mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/login")
                .content(loginRequest)
                .contentType("application/json")
                .accept("application/json")
                .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf())
        ).andExpect(result -> assertEquals("/loggedin", result.getResponse().getForwardedUrl()));

    }

    @Test
    void testValidLoginResponse() throws Exception {
        Muser muser = new Muser(1, "Mama", "mama", "mama", LocalDateTime.now());
        List<MuserRole> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        Mockito.when(dao.findByUsername(Mockito.eq("mama"))).thenReturn(muser);

        Mockito.when(muserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(Mockito.eq("mama"))).thenReturn(
            new MuserDetails(muser, roles)
        );

        String loginRequest = mapper.writeValueAsString(new LoginRequest(
            "mama", "mama", false)
        );

        String response = mockMvc.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/login")
            .content(loginRequest)
            .contentType("application/json")
            .accept("application/json")
            .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf())
    ).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
    
    //Fails
    ApiResponse apiResponse = mapper.readValue(response, ApiResponse.class);
    assertEquals("Welcome, You are now logged in!", apiResponse.getMessage());

    }
  

}

Every test works perfectly fine, except when I need to test the response body.
Here are some of the results:





Well your login successful shows you return a 200 without a body, so getting it returns null and Jackson cannot read null. If you expect mockMvc to actually call the forwarded URL it won't work like that

I thought, since the forwarding happens purely on the server, It should be able to do all that and then it would just return a response,

Maybe there is some documentation about forwarding request with mockMcv and have your desired output

Since you use mockMcv you should not expect it to behave like an actual server. You probably want to do an integration test if you want to test it all at once. Maybe test sur URL received and ask mockMvc to perform a call to it if you really want it all mocked
